# Nauty and Traces on Mac OS X

Tags: c, xcode, macos

I am trying to use the code Nauty and Traces http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/. But when I complied an example, say nautyex8.c (provided by the package), the following error showed up:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_alloc_error", referenced from:
      _main in nautyex8-54d9da.o
  "_densenauty", referenced from:
      _main in nautyex8-54d9da.o
  "_dispatch_graph", referenced from:
      _main.options in nautyex8-54d9da.o
  "_nauty_check", referenced from:
      _main in nautyex8-54d9da.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am using Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10.5) and Xcode (version 7.1). I believe that there is no error in the codes because they are widely used so I guess the problem comes from my system settings.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Instead of trying to build stuff like this from scratch just install a decent package manager, e.g. [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), then it's just a matter of typing `sudo brew install nauty`.

Comment: Those errors come from the linker and indicate that you're missing a library. You need to specify the library on the command line, assuming that the library exists for Mac OS X.

Comment: @PaulR: Unfortunately, `brew install nauty` doesn't work; there's no such formula. So OP's choice to build it locally isn't totally crazy.

Answer (score 1):

I've just opened a pull request to make `brew install nauty` work on OS X: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/48701

Until then, here's how you would build nautyex8.c on OS X, as of Nauty/Traces 2.6r12.
Step 1 is to download the code and build the library:

```
wget http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/nauty26r12.tar.gz
tar zxvf nauty26r12.tar.gz
cd nauty26r12
./configure
make
ls -l nauty.a
```

Step 2 is to compile nautyex8.c and **link it against the library you just built**:

```
gcc -O3 nautyex8.c nauty.a
./a.out
```

You probably forgot to put that "`nauty.a`" at the end of your compiler command line. If I do that too, I get:

```
gcc -O3 nautyex8.c
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_alloc_error", referenced from:
      _main in nautyex8-05f086.o
  "_densenauty", referenced from:
      _main in nautyex8-05f086.o
  "_dispatch_graph", referenced from:
      _main.options in nautyex8-05f086.o
  "_nauty_check", referenced from:
      _main in nautyex8-05f086.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

which exactly matches the symptom you described.